# fuzzwuzzy package : the mathematical formula of fonctions

Tags: formula, calculation, fuzzywuzzy

I want to know the mathematical formula for the package "fuzzwuzzy" of:
- ratio 
- partial_ratio 
- token_set_ratio

For example, I want to be able to calculate the partial_ratio between :"Mark!" & "mark".

Answer (score 0):

I find in the source code! 
So:

- ratio = 2.0*M / T , where M = matches , T = total number of elements in both sequences